# cp -R vs Super-duper vs CCC

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I have my macOS user home on external TB drive. I'd like to keep copies on two different TB drives.

Is there a difference between:

cp -Rv /Volumes/extdrive/myhome  /Volumes/extdrive2

and using Super-duper / CCC to do the same thing?

Comment: Superduper/CCC will nly copy chnaged files and will deal with hard links

Comment: There is also the command `rsync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. In fact, I suspect there are several.

One of the most obvious is that when you delete a file in your Home directory, the `cp` command won’t know to delete it from the other drives.

Also, `cp` isn’t smart enough to know if a file has changed or not, so it’s going to copy all of your files each time you run it, which is going to be a huge waste of time for the majority of your data.

Then there are permissions, and special files, and so forth.

So, in short, don’t use `cp` for this.

`rsync` would be a much better choice than `cp` … but, having said that, I should add that I firmly believe there are only 2 kinds of people in the world:

1. people who have accidentally deleted data with rsync, and
2. people who have never used rsync.

Which is to say, be careful with `rsync`, especially when using it to delete files. Start with a small set of files/folders which are either duplicated/backed up somewhere safe or unimportant, and don’t forget to use `--dry-run` before you run a new `rsync` command.

Personally, I think CCC or SuperDuper are well worth the money (in fact, I own them both), and would much rather use them than any other method of making a backup.